# RavenDB Database.Document file meaning

Tags: ravendb, database-administration

I want to restore my database on RavenDB from a backup. But take an error - Database.Document file is missing.

Can anyone explain me, what is this a file? Where can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file is used to store the db settings for the database. For example, whatever incremental backup it on, what buffer size to use, etc.

Comment: Thanks! Is this file must to be with back up files or not?